# Get Favourite Marked Tweets Updated Date

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, tweets, sttwitter

I am integrating Twitter in an iOS app. The functionality is that i have to get all tweets that are marked favorite within last 24 hours.
I am using "STTwitterAPI" library for getting tweets.

```
Here is my request:-  
 `STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIWithOAuthConsumerKey:@"ConsumerKey" consumerSecret:@"consumerSecret" oauthToken:@"oauthToken" oauthTokenSecret:@"oauthTokenSecret"];
`

`[twitter getFavoritesListWithUserID:nil screenName:nil count:nil sinceID:nil maxID:nil includeEntities:nil successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses){
  NSLog(@"%@",statuses);
}
`

So thats how i am requesting for favourites tweets.
The response coming is that:-

`
contributors = "<null>";
    coordinates = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "Mon May 11 06:20:03 +0000 2015";
    entities =     {
        hashtags =         (
        );
        symbols =         (
        );
        urls =         (
        );
        "user_mentions" =         (
        );
    };
    "favorite_count" = 1;
    favorited = 1;
    geo = "<null>";
    id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    "id_str" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    "in_reply_to_screen_name" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_status_id" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_user_id" = "<null>";
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str" = "<null>";
    lang = en;
    place = "<null>";
    "retweet_count" = 0;
    retweeted = 0;
    source = "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>";
    text = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    truncated = 0;
    user =     {
        "contributors_enabled" = 0;
        "created_at" = "Mon Apr 13 12:15:45 +0000 2015";
        "default_profile" = 1;
        "default_profile_image" = 1;
        description = "";
        entities =         {
            description =             {
                urls =                 (
                );
            };
        };
        "favourites_count" = 56;
        "follow_request_sent" = 0;
        "followers_count" = 0;
        following = 0;
        "friends_count" = 2;
        "geo_enabled" = 0;
        id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
        "id_str" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
        "is_translation_enabled" = 0;
        "is_translator" = 0;
        lang = en;
        "listed_count" = 0;
        location = "";
        name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        notifications = 0;
        "profile_background_color" = C0DEED;
        "profile_background_image_url" = "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
        "profile_background_image_url_https" = "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png";
        "profile_background_tile" = 0;
        "profile_image_url" = "http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png";
        "profile_image_url_https" = "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png";
        "profile_link_color" = 0084B4;
        "profile_sidebar_border_color" = C0DEED;
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color" = DDEEF6;
        "profile_text_color" = 333333;
        "profile_use_background_image" = 1;
        protected = 0;
        "screen_name" = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        "statuses_count" = 11;
        "time_zone" = "<null>";
        url = "<null>";
        "utc_offset" = "<null>";
        verified = 0;
    };
`



I am getting all the favorite marked tweets but i am getting their created date only. Is there ant way so that i can also find their favorite marked time and date too????
```

Suppose i ahev a tweet that i have created 3 months ago. Now i marked him favourite 30 mins ago. So the time that i require is 30 mins previous to current time not the time 3 months ago. Is there any Suggestions???

```
Please Reply Soon....

Thanks...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Can't you just simply use the field "created_at" = "Mon May 11 06:20:03 +0000 2015" and check that this date is within the last 24 hours?

Comment: @nst Thanks for reply. The thing is that "created_at" is not the thing i want. Suppose i have a tweet 2 months old. So its created date is 2 months back. But today i marked it favorite. Now if i want all the tweets that are favorite within last 24 hours, it would not come as its "created_at" is still 2 months back. Thats the problem.

Comment: Then you should try private endpoints like /activity/* see STTwitter methods here  https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/STTwitterAPI.h#L1999 note that your app cannot rely on them since they can disappear at anytime and also require using Twitter's own consumer tokens.